# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT Manual

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a MySQL table and a table has a row with `id` and it has `auto_incremented`. Let's say via MySQL query and PHP, I add a row. The first row has `id` of `1`. Then I manually add a second row (via phpmyadmin) with the `id` of `2`. If I do a third MySQL insert via PHP... what would the `id` be for the third row... `2` or `3`?

Question is... does `auto_increment` take into account manual inputs?

Comment: Why don't you just try it on a test database? ;-)

Comment: You won't get clashes, so next one would be 3. However, you should never manually change or tamper with the value of auto_increment field. Just let the database handle it.

Comment: @N.B. Are you sure you won't get clashes? I tested it, and got a duplicate key error.

Comment: Exactly, you got the error. Hence, you didn't get 2 entries in the db. That's why you don't tamper with the auto_increment manually. But from the example provided in the question - it won't generate a clash (or error if you will).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does auto_increment take into account manual inputs?

Yes it does. But I hope you do not really type in the ID manually, right? :-) Just leave this field alone when inserting (manually or programatically), MySQL will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does accept manual inputs, and it WILL try to set the value you offer. If the value does not exist, it gets inserted, else you get a duplicate key error.

- Put a value when you want to decide a value yourself (for example,
  you deleted a line, and now want the exact same line in the table).
- Put `NULL` or leave the column out of the insert to let the database
  use the auto-increment.

Just a hint: when your application is choosing the values to put for an autoincrement value, you are probably doing something wrong.